# Alpine pi 4 hwclock/swclock

Tags: pi-4

I am trying to use a Pi 4 with I2C DS3231 hardware clock, on alpine 3.11.5 aarch64. I have activated the i2c bus, and followed the [wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Saving_time_with_Hardware_Clock) to add the `start_pre` code.

But at boot time, I have an error.

I looked at the `hwclock` script, it tries to set kernel's TZ, but I have :

```
hwclock: settimeofday: Invalid argument
```

The commandline is `hwclock --systz --utc`.

Then the command that really sets time from DS3231 works fine.

But since the script adds return values, it displays `Failed to set the system clock`.

Also, I tried to disable `swclock` that save/restore the time based on shutdown/reboots, but it stills survive the reboots (I am working in data mode, and I `lbu ci -d` each time).

What have I missed ?

Comment: What OS? I suggest that following obsolete tutorials (anything 3 years old has to be handled with caution) is a bad idea.

Comment: Alpine linux 3.11.5 aarch64 (latest at time of writing). I know what is an "old tutorial", and their wiki for hardware clock seams to work out of the box. But the error I have seams to be an error the tool hwclock raises, but I don't know why. The same command launched by hand after boot works fine.
Also, I don't know how to disable `swclock` and persist this disabled state accross reboots